# window.location with 8080 port fails to redirect to another location

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a ReactJS application running on port 8080 of my server.

At a certain screen, I get the following window location:

`console.log(window.location)`:

```
ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList {length: 0}
assign: ƒ ()
hash: ""
host: "170.80.224.142:8000"
hostname: "170.80.224.142"
href: "http://170.80.224.142:8000/"
origin: "http://170.80.224.142:8000"
pathname: "/"
port: "8000"
protocol: "http:"
reload: ƒ reload()
replace: ƒ ()
search: ""
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive): undefined
__proto__: Location
```

This page has the following component:

```
class NavButton extends Component {
    handleModuleNav = action => {
        let to = "/" + action;
        window.location = to;
    };

    render = () => {
        return (
          <div onClick={() => this.handleModuleNav("admin")}>
             GO TO ADMIN
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When clicking in the button, my app is going to "http://170.80.224.142/admin", missing the 8080 port.

How can I make sure the port is added? (The ip address and port may vary, I need to make sure the loaded IP and PORT are going to be used).

Comment: Do you have React-router in your application?

Comment: If so, you can just add the following inside your div `<Link to="/admin">GO TO ADMIN</Link>`

Comment: I'm using react-router V4. Can't use {<Link>} tag... have to handle that on the handleModuleNav due to application behaviour...